# Run R script in a loop

Tags: r, list, dplyr, iteration, lapply

I am analysing output of 96 well plates to get maximum growthrate by using the `growthrates` package in R. The structure of the 96 well plate output file is:

```
Time    A1        A2     A3       A4
0      0.116      0.122  0.144   0.108
```

There are 866 rows in total.
To run `growthrate`, I am extracting Time and first well and anlysing. This is because `growthrate` will not run if the time is repeated.
I wrote a script to run for A1 and A2 which is giving me the output. But the problem is I don't know how to run as a loop for the entire well.

Here is my code:

```
test3
    ## extrcating column 1 and 2
        dat<-test3[,c(1,2)]
        
        fit <- fit_easylinear(dat$Time, dat$A1)
         summary(fit)
        
        
        ##writing as a datframe
        ##A1 result written
         
         A1<-data.frame(coef(fit))

         ##colmn name changed for A1
         colnames(A1) <- c("A1")
        
        dat1 <-test3[,c(1,3)]
        fit2 <- fit_easylinear(dat1$Time, dat1$A2)
        A2<-data.frame(coef(fit))
        colnames(A2) <- c("A2")
        A1$A2<-A2$A2
```

With this code my result is

```
         A1    A2
    y0
    y0_lm
    mumax
    lag
```

I am trying to run the growthrate for all wells (A1-A12) and have the result for all wells as above. Any help at this moment is appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Package growthrates supports data in long format, often also called **tidy data**. In this case, no loops are needed. If, however, the data are in wide format, one should convert the multiple-column data frame into a data frame with time, values and one or more id columns. The documentation of growthrates has examples for this.

Let's start to create some data. Here we use a built-in data set `antibiotic` that is already in "tidy format" and convert it back to wide format, similar to the data set of the original poster. Note that the purpose of this first step is only the creation of some test data!

### 1. Test data set

```r
library("growthrates")
library("dplyr")
library("tidyr")

data("antibiotic")

df <- antibiotic[c("time", "variable", "value")]
levels(df$variable) <- paste0("A", 1:48)
df_wide <- data.frame(pivot_wider(df, names_from ="variable", 
                                  values_from = "value"))

head(df_wide[1:5)
```

The data set looks now like follows:

```
  time          A1          A2          A3          A4
1  0.0 0.008813525 0.008813525 0.008813525 0.009813525
2  0.5 0.009813525 0.009813525 0.009813525 0.010813525
3  1.0 0.012813525 0.012813525 0.012813525 0.012813525
4  1.5 0.017813525 0.016813525 0.016813525 0.016813525
5  2.0 0.022813525 0.023813525 0.023813525 0.023813525
6  2.5 0.033813525 0.034813525 0.034813525 0.033813525
```

### 2. Analysis

Fitting the growth rates with the easylinear method can then be done like follows:

1. Reshape the wide data frame to a long data frame with `pivot_longer`
2. apply `all_easilinear` to the data and specify the data structure with a formula
3. Extract results with accessor functions like `results`, `coef` or `summary`.

```r
df_long <- pivot_longer(df_wide, cols = starts_with("A"), names_to = "well")

fits <- all_easylinear(value ~ time | well, data = df_long)

results(fits)
coef(fits)
summary(fits)
```

Finally, you can plot **all** results at once, just with:

```r
plot(fits)
```

If you use **RStudio** use the navigation arrows in the graphic pane to go back and forth. Or redirect everything to a pdf:

```r
pdf("plots.pdf")
plot(fits)
dev.off()
```

Instead of the `all_easilinear` one can also use another method, see [package vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/growthrates/vignettes/Introduction.html) for examples.

Comment: thank you for your help.  But for fit_easylinear the above method dosenot work as time is duplicated and the script is not made for the duplicated data.

Comment: Iconsider this as a feature request for the future. For now, you can aggregate (e.g. average) the data before calling `all_easilinear`, e.g. by using dplyr's `group_by` and then `summarize`.

Answer (score 2):

An `lapply` here with `bind_cols` should do the trick:

```r
library(growthrates)
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(11)

df <- data.frame(time = seq(0, 865),
           A1 = runif(866, 0, 1),
           A2 = runif(866, 0, 1),
           A3 = runif(866, 0, 1),
           A4 = runif(866, 0, 1),
           A5 = runif(866, 0, 1),
           A6 = runif(866, 0, 1),
           A7 = runif(866, 0, 1),
           A8 = runif(866, 0, 1),
           A9 = runif(866, 0, 1),
           A10 = runif(866, 0, 1),
           A11 = runif(866, 0, 1),
           A12 = runif(866, 0, 1),
           B1 = runif(866, 0, 1),
           B2 = runif(866, 0, 1),
           B3 = runif(866, 0, 1),
           B4 = runif(866, 0, 1),
           B5 = runif(866, 0, 1),
           B6 = runif(866, 0, 1),
           B7 = runif(866, 0, 1),
           B8 = runif(866, 0, 1),
           B9 = runif(866, 0, 1),
           B10 = runif(866, 0, 1),
           B11 = runif(866, 0, 1),
           B12 = runif(866, 0, 1),
           C1 = runif(866, 0, 1),
           C2 = runif(866, 0, 1),
           C3 = runif(866, 0, 1),
           C4 = runif(866, 0, 1),
           C5 = runif(866, 0, 1),
           C6 = runif(866, 0, 1),
           C7 = runif(866, 0, 1),
           C8 = runif(866, 0, 1),
           C9 = runif(866, 0, 1),
           C10 = runif(866, 0, 1),
           C11 = runif(866, 0, 1),
           C12 = runif(866, 0, 1))

df_list <- lapply(2:length(colnames(df)), function(x) data.frame(y = coef(fit_easylinear(df$time, df[[x]]))))
output <- dplyr::bind_cols(df_list)
sample_names <- tibble(Var1 = LETTERS[1:((length(colnames(df))-1)/12)],
       Var2 = rep(list(1:12), times = 3)) %>%
      unnest(Var2)
names(output) <- paste(sample_names$Var1, sample_names$Var2, sep = "")
```

Comment: Thank you @dcsuka This code will work for only A1-A14. I am sorry I should have mentioned it before, my exact data format is A1 A2 A3 A4 A5 A6 A7 A8 A9 A10 A11 A12 B1 B2 B3 B4 B5 B6 B7 B8 B9 B10 B11 B12.... So there are 8 rows (A-H) and 12 colummnns (1-12). I need to run  growthrate foreach column and priint the output as above.

Comment: I was able to run the same code for two rows A and B  by changing this line  df_list <- lapply(2:26, function(x) data.frame(y = coef(fit_easylinear(test6$Time, test6[[x]]))))df_list <- lapply(2:26, function(x) data.frame(y = coef(fit_easylinear(test6$Time, test6[[x]])))). But when I tried to run for all which woould be 108 columns, I am getting error.

Comment: I don't think there would be 108 columns, 12 * 8 = 96. My code above generalizes to any number of letters, I edited it. If this works, make sure to leave a greeen check mark so others can see it is correct.

Comment: Thank you @dcsuka for the edi. Yes, it should be 96. As I am poor to edit such complex script I have one  concern where in the last part the column names are changed.  I believe  the column name format should be A1, A2, A3, A4, A5 ,A6,A7,A8,A9,A10,A11,A12,B1,B2,B3,B4.... But with this code it is A1,B1,C1,D1,E1,F1,H1. How should I fix this one?

Comment: Sorry, I think I fixed it now.

Comment: Thank you soo much. It worked. If it is possible for you, could you help me understand the code with some comments. I really want to learn and improve my skills. I know the general skeleton of functions but I am still learning. thank you for your time @dcsuka

Comment: Sure, you can try runing each section individually, and each subsection individually as well. For, example, run `2:length(colnames(df))` and `length(colnames(df))-1`, among many others. The `lapply` step creates a list of dataframes of coefficients between time and every other column of the dataframe. `bind_cols` joins them. The rest of the code just sets the names of that bound dataframe correctly, and it will be more clear if you run it.

Comment: I am ruuning for my data and I am getting error with this part of the code sample_names <- tibble(Var1 = LETTERS[1:((length(colnames(test6))-1)/12)],
                       Var2 = rep(list(1:12), times = 3)) %>%
  unnest(Var2)     where I only changed dataframe name to test6 . The error says: Error:
 Tibble columns must have compatible sizes.
 Size 8: Existing data.
 Size 3: Column `Var2`.
 Only values of size one are recycled. I am not sure how to fix this one. I ran individual part.

Comment: Try changing times to 8, or however many letters you need. If that fails, can you add a `dput(df)` of your data set to your main question?

Comment: Thank you changing times= 8 worked. I really appreaciate your all help. @dcsuka

Comment: after multiple attempts I am reaching out you again. Is there anyway to run the above code and store the fit result.                                                                                    
 df_list <- lapply(2:length(colnames(df)), function(x) data.frame(y = coef(fit_easylinear(df$time, df[[x]])))) . I need to plot only fit result (not coefficient) for each well. I tried editing the code but I am not able to make it work.

Comment: Hi again! This code makes a list of all of the fit lengths. `fit_list <- lapply(2:length(colnames(df)), function(x) fit_easylinear(df$time, df[[x]]))
`

Comment: Thank you, after I ran above code I ran plot(unlist(fit_list)) assuming that this is the way to plot list. But I am getting error saying x is a list but dose not have x and y which I don't know how to debugg.

Comment: Try this: `for (i in seq_along(fit_list)) {
  jpeg(paste0("Desktop/images/", colnames(df)[i+1], ".jpg"));
  plot(slot(fit_list[[i]], "obs"));
  dev.off()
}`

Comment: It worked: Can you commment a little about above code. I understood by extracting fit_list[[i]]  it  is the fit result but I don't undertand much of the part. Thank you soo much for your time!

Comment: The paste0 part makes the filename, the jpeg saves the following plot, the slot takes the df out of the fit class, the plot plots it, and the dev.off finishes the saving.

Comment: But why the plot figure is not indicating where actually the fit is.  I am talking as reference to this page https://tpetzoldt.github.io/growthrates/doc/Introduction.html where when you plot the fit there are red dots to show where the fit is. And also a line is there to indicate the fit.

Comment: `for (i in seq_along(fit_list)) {
  jpeg(paste0("Desktop/images/", colnames(df)[i+1], ".jpg"))
  plot(fit_list[[i]])
  dev.off()}`

Comment: maybe take the slot out. It errs with my example data, but try it on your real data

Comment: with this code for (i in seq_along(fit_list)) {jpeg(paste0("C:/Desktop/images/", colnames(test6)[i+1], ".jpg"));plot(fit_list[[i]], "obs");dev.off() }   I am getting this error: Error in as.double(x) : 
  cannot coerce type 'S4' to vector of type 'double'

Comment: The "obs" is not in the code I sent you

Comment: I am sorry I missed your code earlier:   I am getting error Error: unexpected symbol in "for (i in seq_along(fit_list)) {   jpeg(paste0("C:/Users/Desktop/images", colnames(test6)[i+1], ".jpg"))   plot"     I tried to solve it by changing the code as by adding ; for (i in seq_along(fit_list)) {jpeg(paste0("C:/Users/Desktop/images", colnames(test6)[i+1], ".jpg")); plot(fit_list[[i]]);   dev.off()} and now I am getting error as : Error in seq.default(min(obs[, "time"] + lag), max(obs[, "time"]), length = 200) :

Comment: I think I got something similar, but it only happens in some variables if i am not mistaken. Experiment with trying only on one variable, then go forward. I cannot see your data, so its hard to help with that.

Comment: I tried to plot for individual with-- plot(fit_list[[6]]) I am getting same error for all. How should I share my data here?

Comment: What about with the sample data I sent?

Comment: With your data set, code run, but there is not plo. I tried to put here my data through dput but its too long and is not leeting me upload.

Comment: You might want to ask a separate question, as this is another matter. You can send me the link, and I may try to answer.