# Plotting fit result in loop growthrate package in r

Tags: r

I am  using fit_easylinear for my 96 well plates data. From growthrate I am using fit_easylinear for which the data should not duplicated. In my data, time is duplicated for each well (A!,A2,A3 etc). With the help of one of the stackoverflow user, I am able to run fit_easylinear in a loop but I am struggling to make the plots for fit result. The code that I have so far:

```
 library(growthrates)
    library(tidyverse)
    
    set.seed(11)
    
    df <- data.frame(time = seq(0, 865),
                     A1 = runif(866, 0, 1),
                     A2 = runif(866, 0, 1),
                     A3 = runif(866, 0, 1),
                     A4 = runif(866, 0, 1),
                     A5 = runif(866, 0, 1),
                     A6 = runif(866, 0, 1),
                     A7 = runif(866, 0, 1),
                     A8 = runif(866, 0, 1),
                     A9 = runif(866, 0, 1),
                     A10 = runif(866, 0, 1),
                     A11 = runif(866, 0, 1),
                     A12 = runif(866, 0, 1),
                     B1 = runif(866, 0, 1),
                     B2 = runif(866, 0, 1),
                     B3 = runif(866, 0, 1),
                     B4 = runif(866, 0, 1),
                     B5 = runif(866, 0, 1),
                     B6 = runif(866, 0, 1),
                     B7 = runif(866, 0, 1),
                     B8 = runif(866, 0, 1),
                     B9 = runif(866, 0, 1),
                     B10 = runif(866, 0, 1),
                     B11 = runif(866, 0, 1),
                     B12 = runif(866, 0, 1),
                     C1 = runif(866, 0, 1),
                     C2 = runif(866, 0, 1),
                     C3 = runif(866, 0, 1),
                     C4 = runif(866, 0, 1),
                     C5 = runif(866, 0, 1),
                     C6 = runif(866, 0, 1),
                     C7 = runif(866, 0, 1),
                     C8 = runif(866, 0, 1),
                     C9 = runif(866, 0, 1),
                     C10 = runif(866, 0, 1),
                     C11 = runif(866, 0, 1),
                     C12 = runif(866, 0, 1))
    
    
    
    
    ###################### fit easy linear model 
    
    
    fit_list <- lapply(2:length(colnames(df)), function(x) fit_easylinear(df$time, df[[x]]))
```

######This plots all the values but dose not show the actual fit
for (i in seq_along(fit_list)) {jpeg(paste0("C:/Users/Desktop/images/", colnames(df)[i+1], ".jpg"));   plot(slot(fit_list[[i]], "obs"));   dev.off() }

```
###### removed slot from the code
    
 for (i in seq_along(fit_list)) {jpeg(paste0("C:/Users/Rahul/Desktop/images", colnames(df)[i+1], ".jpg"));plot(fit_list[[i]]) ;dev.off()}    
    

From th above line of code gives me error as Error in seq.default(min(obs[, "time"] + lag), max(obs[, "time"]), length = 200) : 
      'from' must be a finite number
```

Comment: The example data are not suitable for a useful  demonstation. They are just random, without any signal. Please use another data set, e.g. the one provided in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73627555/3677576).

Answer (score 0):

As said in [my previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73627555/3677576) it is almost always better to work with data in long format, especially as the package explicitly supports this. However, the result of the `lapply` call from above can also be plotted with `lapply`.

Instead of purely random data, let's use another, little bit more realistic example of an exponentially growing population:

```r
df <- data.frame(
  time = 1:10,
  A1 = c(1.12, 1.27, 1.18, 1.49, 1.58, 1.84, 2.19, 2.32, 2.6, 2.72),
  A2 = c(1.23, 1.54, 1.65, 2.23, 2.65, 3.33, 4.23, 5.04, 6.19, 7.39),
  A3 = c(1.36, 1.87, 2.29, 3.32, 4.42, 6.06, 8.34, 11.11, 15.02, 20.09),
  B1 = c(1.5, 2.27, 3.15, 4.96, 7.32, 11.04, 16.62, 24.62, 36.74, 54.6),
  B2 = c(1.66, 2.77, 4.31, 7.39, 12.12, 20.1, 33.29, 54.69, 90.16, 148.42),
  B3 = c(1.84, 3.37, 5.88, 11.03, 20.02, 36.61, 66.86, 121.6, 221.55, 403.43)
)

fit_list <- lapply(2:length(colnames(df)), function(x) fit_easylinear(df$time, df[[x]]))

par(mfrow=c(2, 3))
dummy <- lapply(fit_list, plot)
```

The `dummy` variable is just intended to suppress the unnecessary output of `lapply`. One can also enclose the `lapply`within `invisible()`.

[image: plot growth curves]